# largest parallelogram in triangle (optimization problem)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

[image: largest parallelogram in triangle]

Consider a parallelogram inscribed in a triangle ABC in such a way that one vertex coincides with A while the others fall one on each side of the triangle. The maximum possible area for such a parallelogram is what fraction of the area of the original triangle?

**Hint**. Orient the triangle so that its vertices are $A = (0, 0)$, $B = (a, 0)$, and $C = (b, c)$. Let $(t, 0)$ be the vertex of the parallelogram lying on $AB$ and $(x, y)$ be the vertex lying on $BC$. Use $t$ as the independent variable. Find $x$ and $y $in terms of $t$ (and the constants $a, b$, and $c$)

I have solved it before, but I totally forget how; my answer was half (the source didn't include the answer)

Comment: Please draw a picture and show how that parallelogram is *inscribed* into the triangle.

Comment: The answer is indeed $\frac12$ of the area of the original triangle, and there are many ways of showing this, including using an affine transformation and the fact that $z(1-z)\le \frac14$.

Comment: can you explain in detail ? 
I have studied calc 1 and 2 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the set-up in your "Hint":

- $\triangle ABC$ has base length $a$.
- There is a triangle $T_1$ above the parallelogram, similar to $\triangle ABC$, with base length $t$.
- There is a triangle $T_2$ to the right of the parallelogram, similar to $\triangle ABC$, with base length $a-t$.

$\begin{align}
\text{Area}_{\text{parallelogram}}&=\text{Area}_{\triangle ABC}-\text{Area}_{\triangle T_1}-\text{Area}_{\triangle T_2}\\
&=\left(1-\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)^2-\left(\frac{a-t}{a}\right)^2\right)\text{Area}_{\triangle ABC}\\
&=\left(\frac12-\frac{2}{a^2}\left(t-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2\right)\text{Area}_{\triangle ABC}\\
&\le \dfrac12\text{Area}_{\triangle ABC}\\
\end{align}$